# Overriding the bin directory

Tags: msbuild

I am writing a MSBuild script for creating a one click deployment.  Everything works great but the files are created in the app.publish under the bin directory.  Is there a way to set the output directory to another directory instead of the default bin directory?

I used PublishDir but that just creates the setup.exe in the specified directory.  The other files are still created under the bin directory.

Can route all the one click deployments to a specific directory or do I have to copy later?

Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried OutputPath instead?

```
msbuild my_solution.sln /p:OutputPath=c:\my_dir
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work.  Here is my command D:\>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /nologo "D:\T\UTI-
IT\DEV\Maintenance_20130213\src\LMSIntegrationTool\LMSScheduling.sln" /m:1 /targ
et:publish /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:Configurat
ion=QA /p:DeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:MsDeployServiceURL=corpdevweb11 /p:AllowU
ntrustedCertificate=true /p:PublishURL=http://lmsschedulerqa/ /p:UpdateURL=http:
//lmsschedulerqa/ /p:OutDir="D:\buildoutput\\"
 /p:RunCodeAnalysis="False" /p:PublishDir="D:\buildoutput\Package"